# How to pass parameter to python script from an Azure Data Factory pipeline

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-data-factory, pipeline, azure-databricks

I am building an Azure Data Factory pipeline and I would like to know how to get this [parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kga47.png) into the python script.

The python script is located in Databricks (DBFS) and is run from Azure DataFactory. So, in my ADF pipeline, I have some parameters which I'd like to introduce and use them insinde the python script.

Any idea on how does it work?

Comment: do you mean how to get this parameter from inside the python script? have you tried `os.argv` ?

Comment: I finally did it importing argv from sys. If you have a parameter on your pipleine you can get it inside the python script typing **argv[1]** (index 0 contains the related path). I guess it works as well with os.argv. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import argv from sys and then use `argv[1]` to get the parameter in databricks activity.

Comment: any way of sending parameters as keywords and not as positional?